# StreamBuilder inside RefreshIndicator render child widget many times, how to avoid it?

Tags: flutter

When I put StreamBuilder in RefreshIndicator, it render widgets many times with scroll actions. I want to avoid many it because Charts inside `StreamBuilder` animate many times.

I tested with following environment.

```
$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G5019, locale en-JP)
    • Flutter version 1.2.1 at /Users/matsue/work/flutter/flutter_macos_v1.0.0-stable
    • Framework revision 8661d8aecd (4 weeks ago), 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
    • Engine revision 3757390fa4
    • Dart version 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)
```

[image: output]

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxScrolled) => [
            const SliverAppBar(
              title: Text('Title'),
            ),
          ],
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () async {
          print('Will refresh');
          await Future<void>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
          print('Did refresh');
        },
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: _streamController.stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) => ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 30,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  print('Render $index');
                  return Text('index $index');
                },
              ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I want to put some `StreamBuilder` inside `RefreshIndicator` without widgets rendering many times.

Comment: I am having the same situation. Please try to update if you found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like StreamBuilder re-subscribes on the stream and triggers re-rendering.
Swapping it with RefreshIndicator helps:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxScrolled) => [
              const SliverAppBar(
                title: Text('Title'),
              ),
            ],
        body: StreamBuilder(
          key: streamBuilderKey,
          stream: _streamController.stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            print(snapshot.connectionState);
            return RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: () async {
                print('Will refresh');
                await Future<void>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
                _streamController.add(null);
                print('Did refresh');
              },
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 30,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  print('Render $index');
                  return Text(
                    'index $index',
                    key: Key('$index'),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have multiple StreamBuilders inside a single RefreshIndicator. So in my case I can't wrap the RefreshIndicator with StreamBuilder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I want to put StreamBuilder in RefreshIndicator because my app handles some BLoCs.