# List view item builder calls multiple times

Tags: flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app

I have an infinite list like below. But item builder works multiple times after loading data, i don't understand when it happen, sometimes when scrolling happen, sometimes after initial data load . So it call `FlashNewsCard` build function multiple times as well as `buildNewsCard` function. Is any way to restrict this behaviour.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    newsBloc = NewsBloc();
    newsBloc.newsEventSink.add(MoreNewsEvent());
    widget.scrollController.addListener(_onScroll);
  }

===============================

         ListView.builder(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: newsBloc.hasReachedmax
                    ? snapshot.data.length + 1
                    : snapshot.data.length + 2,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if (index == 0) {
                    return FlashNewsCard();
                  }
                  index -= 1;
                  return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          bottom: 4.0, left: 6.0, right: 5.0),
                      child: buildNewsCard(index, snapshot));
                })
```

Bloc class

```
class NewsBloc {

  final _newsStateController =StreamController<List<News>>();

  StreamSink<List<News>> get
  _inNewsList =>_newsStateController.sink;

  Stream<List<News>> get
  newsList =>_newsStateController.stream;

  final _newsEventController =StreamController<NewsEvent>();

  StreamSink<NewsEvent> get
  newsEventSink =>_newsEventController.sink;

  NewsBloc() {
    _newsEventController.stream.listen(_mapStateToEvent);
  }

  void _mapStateToEvent(NewsEvent newsEvent) async {

    final newses =await fetchNewFromApi ();

    _inNewsList.add(newses)

  }

}
```

I checked the stream controller and it serve data correctly. Also i want to build `FlashNewsCard` widget to build only at initial data load.

**UPDATE : The stream builder for the listview is inside the refreshindicator widget.**

Found a similar question [StreamBuilder inside RefreshIndicator render child widget many times, how to avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56713145/streambuilder-inside-refreshindicator-render-child-widget-many-times-how-to-avo) but couldn't find a solution

Comment: are you using a provider or a stream builder to get newsBloc list?

Comment: @jitsm555 stream builder

Comment: I think you are getting data from your stream builder continuously, Do check with debugging or add logs

Comment: @azhar Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @Blasanka No. i checked the stream controller and it serves data correctly.

Comment: @Blasanka i updated the question with more details

Comment: @azhar Cant it be this: `widget.scrollController.addListener(_onScroll);` line causing the issue. It is very hard to understand. I guess you trying to add pagination. Please can you give an idea of what you trying to achieve.

Comment: @Blasanka updated the question with link to a question which i found to be similar

Answer (score 0):

StreamBuilder rebuilds its children when changes in Stream has been detected. If you like to only load the Stream once, you can initialize the Stream on `initState()`. This should prevent rebuilding the children widget.

```dart
late Stream _stream;

@override
initState() {
  super.initState();
  ...
  _stream = yourStream();
}

@override
Widget build() {
  return StreamBuilder(stream: _stream, ...);
}
```